# Windows Live Contact API The requested url was not found on this server?

Tags: php, html, hotmail, windows-live, import-contacts

I am trying to get my hotmail contacts from the Windows Live Contacts API. I followed a tutorial and downloaded the php and html code. Eventhough it should work and it gives me a key back, It wont show anything.

When I try to get the contacts it first asks my permission, after that i'll return to my own page automatically and thats when i get a error.

> Error: Not Found 
> The requested URL
>   /result.php?code=xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx was not found
>   on this server.

Index.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id='.$client_id.'&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.emails%20wl.contacts_emails&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri;
?>

<html>
  <body link="#0C6182" vlink="#0C6182" alink="#0C6182">
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>" style="text-decoration: none"> Invite Friends From Hotmail</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result.php

```
<?php

session_start();

function curl_file_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

?>
<html>
<body >
<div align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                //setting parameters

                include('config.php');

                $auth_code = $_GET["code"];
                $fields=array(
                    'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
                    'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
                    'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
                    'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
                    'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
                );

                $post = '';
                foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }

                $post = rtrim($post,'&');
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf');
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
                $result = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                $response =  json_decode($result);
                $accesstoken = $response->access_token;

                $url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token='.$accesstoken;
                $xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
                $xml = json_decode($xmlresponse, true);
                $contacts_email = "";

                $count = 0;
                foreach ($xml['data'] as $title) {
                    $count++;

                    echo $count.". ".$title['emails']['personal'] . "<br><br>";

                }

                ?>

                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'xxxxxxxxx';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WindowsLive is not able to, after user consent, properly redirect to your `$redirect_uri`: please verify if the value is correct.